# Manipulating R Data Frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I've currently got two separate data frames, excerpts as per below:

mydata

```
Player  TG% Pts Team    Opp Yr      Rd  Grnd
John    56  42  A       1   2015    1   Grnd1
James   94  64  B       2   2015    1   Grnd2
Jerry   85  78  C       3   2015    1   Grnd3
Daniel  97  51  D       4   2015    1   Grnd4
John    89  61  A       1   2015    1   Grnd2
James   65  26  B       4   2015    1   Grnd3
Jerry   73  34  C       3   2015    1   Grnd2
Daniel  73  40  D       2   2015    1   Grnd2
John    89  26  A       1   2015    1   Grnd3
James   92  42  B       3   2015    1   Grnd1
Jerry   89  25  C       2   2015    1   Grnd2
Daniel  80  41  D       4   2015    1   Grnd2
John    73  82  A       3   2015    1   Grnd3
James   73  41  B       4   2015    1   Grnd3
Jerry   89  76  C       2   2015    1   Grnd1
Daniel  91  77  D       1   2015    1   Grnd2
```

round

```
Team   Opp    Grnd
A      1      Grnd1
B      3      Grnd4
C      4      Grnd2
D      2      Grnd3
```

What I want to be able to do is manipulate this so that I generate a second data frame as per below

```
Player   Gms   Avg.Pts   Avg.Last3   Avg.v.Opp   Avg.@.Grnd
John
James
Jerry
Daniel
```

I know how to do this in Excel, however I'm struggling in R

Gms - total number of games for each individual player (excel would be countif)

Avg.Pts - this is the average of Pts for each Player name (excel would be averageif)

Avg.Last3 - this is the average of Pts for each Player in their last 3 games, note that the data frame is in order with most recent games at the end of the data frame.

Avg.v.Opp - this is the average of Pts for each player against the next opponent as defined in data frame round. For example John plays for team A and his next opponent is Opp 1. (excel would be averageifs)

Avg.@.Grnd - this is the average of Pts for each player at the next ground as defined in data fram round. For example John plays for team A and his next game is held at Grnd1. (excel would be averageifs)

I've tried using dplyr and a number of other options but haven't seemed to successfully put together something that works at this stage. Note that mydata data frame runs to over 10,000+ rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work. If you share your sample data with `dput()`, I'll be happy to copy/paste it and check (and debug if necessary).

First I'll do the easy ones, the ones that don't depend on `round`:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(mydata, Player) %>%
   summarize(Gms = n(),
       Avg.Pts = mean(Pts),
       Avg.Last3 = mean(tail(Pts, 3)))
```

I wanted to do that one separately to emphasize how clean `dplyr` can be for simple cases. All the "ifs" in your Excel commands are taken care of by the single `group_by` at the beginning. `n()` is the count, and `mean()` is the average. `tail()` is a handy base function that returns the end of a data frame or vector.

To add in the `round` data, we'll want to join the data frames together based on the `Team` column. We still we'll want to be able to tell the other columns apart whether they're from `mydata` or `round`, so I'll rename the `round` columns:

```
round = rename(round, next_opp = Opp, next_grnd = Grnd)
```

Then we'll start with the `join` and proceed as before. This time we *do* need some `if`s at the end, which I'll do with a simple subset inside the `mean` calls:

```
left_join(mydata, round) %>%
  # convert ground columns to character as discussed in comments
  mutate(next_grnd = as.character(next_grnd),
       Grnd = as.character(Grnd)) %>%
  group_by(Player) %>%
  summarize(Gms = n(),
       Avg.Pts = mean(Pts),
       Avg.Last3 = mean(tail(Pts, 3)),
       Avg.v.Opp = mean(Pts[Opp == next_opp]),
       Avg.at.Grnd = mean(Pts[Grnd == next_grnd]))
```

Comment: This works great, all except for 'Avg.at.Grnd = mean(Pts[Grnd == next_grnd])', I get an error of _Error: level sets of factors are different_. This may have something to do with the fact that not all grounds are played at every week.

Comment: Yeah, if you convert both `Grnd` and `next_grnd` to character rather than factor columns that will take care of it. I'll edit in the changes to do it in `dplyr`.

Comment: Excellent, thankyou very much, this is very much appreciated.

Comment: once last thing, if I wanted to add a column showing number of games that v Opponent, what would be needed here? Could the 'count' function be used?

Comment: I would think something like `sum(Opp == next_opp)`.